# Terminal line has broken itself when type long characters on OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line-interface, line

I use Terminal very Often which mean is i have situation that i have to put long phrase for executing command from Terminal to App.
I have no idea when this line sucking( or breaking) had been happening now.
is there any solution to fix this without sizing of terminal?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's hard to see what is the problem exactly from the two screenshots. Sometimes my terminal is messed up because after starting a new command line, the cursor is overlapping text, but usually, typing "enter" makes it ok again. Obviously, this is not your problem here?

Comment: i want to prevent overlapping it cause mistake to modify or type.
Also i don't want to press enter or re-size it every time. :(
i uploaded video for it Thanks.
https://youtu.be/f2pAQOkUSKk

Comment: Thanks for taking the time providing the video. Your prompt customization is likely to be messed up. Can you write down the result of this command ? `grep "export PS1=" ~/.* 2>/dev/null`

Comment: (14:42:55) Logan@Annoymous gitlab $ grep "export PS1=" ~/.* 2>/dev/null
/Users/Logan/.bash_profile:export PS1="\u@\h \W\[\033[32m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
(14:43:03) Logan@Annoymous gitlab $

sorry for late reply

Answer (score 2):

Based on our discussion, you should edit your `~/.bash_profile` and replace the following line:

```
export PS1="\u@\h \W[\033[32m]\$(parse_git_branch)[\033[00m] $ "
```

with this line:

```
export PS1="\u@\h \W\[\033[32m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

Then open a new terminal window, and try if it's any better.

When customizing the PS1 variable, you need to surround non-printable character with `\[` and `\]` or else bash doesn't calculate the length of the prompt correctly, hence the overlapping text with the cursor.

---

**UPDATE**

I would just replace this block of code:

```
parse_git_branch() {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* (.*)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="\u@\h \W[\033[32m]\$(parse_git_branch)[\033[00m] $ "
```

with this line:

```
export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\] \[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\] (\$(git branch 2>/dev/null | grep '^*' | colrm 1 2)) \$ "
```

---

Or, if you want to stick with your solution, replace it with this correction:

```
parse_git_branch() {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

export PS1="\u@\h \W\[\033[32m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

---

**UPDATE2**

Replace this line:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="echo -n \(\$(date +%H:%M:%S)\)\ "
```

With this line:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND=update_terminal_cwd
```

Now your terminal should be OK again! If you want to add the date and time in front of your prompt, 
Then edit this line:

```
export PS1="\u@\h \W\[\033[32m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

like this:

```
export PS1="($(date +%H:%M:%S)) \u@\h \W\[\033[32m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

Comment: well i still have same symptom.. i would like show this lines.
===================================
 66 # Terminal TimeStamp
 67 export PROMPT_COMMAND="echo -n \(\$(date +%H:%M:%S)\)\ "
 68 
 69 # Git branch in prompt.
 70 parse_git_branch() {
 71   git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
 72 }
 73 export PS1="\u@\h \W\[\033[32m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "

Comment: I think the function `parse_git_branch()` is broken. I updated my message to suggest another line.

Comment: The PROMPT_COMMAND is the one messing it up, but commenting it won't be enough, see my update2 in my answer...

Comment: awesome, finally it fixed.! 
Thank you!
Hope you have Brilliant Day with Full of Luck!